# Login Error: Error: A case reducer on a non-draftable value must not return undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

In my userSlice.js file, I have the following code. and when I was debugging the loginStart reducer was working then it jumps to loginError

Edit: Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't and I can't figure out why

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState: {
      userInfo: null,
      loginPending: false,
      loginError: false,
      isLoggedIn: false,
      token: '',
    },
    reducers: {
        loginStart: (state) => {
            state.loginPending = true;
        },
        loginSuccess: (state, action) => {
            state.loginPending = false;
            state.userInfo = action.payload.dashboardUser;
            state.token = action.payload.token;
            state.isLoggedIn = true;
        },
        loginError: (state) => {
            state.loginError = true;
            state.loginPending = false;
        },
        logout: async (state) => {
            state.token = '';
            state.isLoggedIn = false;
            state.userInfo = null;
        }
    },
});

export const { loginStart, loginSuccess, loginError, logout } = userSlice.actions;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

and here is the login function:

```
export const login = async (email, password, dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch(loginStart());
        const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER}/api/auth/login`, {
            email: email,
            password: password,
        });
        dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data));
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch(loginError());
    }
}
```

and the login api call is working. So the problem isn't there. I appreciate your help everyone

Answer (score 0):

I saw you wrong url: `process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER}/api//auth/login`. So `axios` cannot post data and it jumps to `loginError`.

update your URL:

```
process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER}/api/auth/login
```

Comment: this isn't it unfortunately. I made a mistake when copying I edited the post now @Viet

Comment: Turned out when I logout and re login this will happen but when I refresh and login it works. Not sure why